# Arising errors in Kivy when root widget comes from an instance from .kv file

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I have a simple code working perfectly, and when I change my root class in .kv file to a root instance, it stop working (something already was working).

In .kv file there are already two lines to test differences between two cases, is a matter of comment one / uncomment the other one

I've asked in Kivy forum, used builder class with no results (because I don't understand where is the difference!). As newbie in Kivy, I have very little instinctive resources right now.

main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
from colorsys import hsv_to_rgb, rgb_to_hsv
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class MoneyControl(Widget):
    cartel = ObjectProperty(None)

    lay = 3
    rainbow = [0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]

    def hsva_to_rgba(self, hsva):
        rgba = hsv_to_rgb(hsva[0], hsva[1], hsva[2])
        rgba = list(rgba)
        rgba.append(hsva[3])
        return rgba

    def update(self, dt):
        self.lay += 1
        self.cartel.text = str(self.lay)
        self.rainbow[0] += self.lay*0.0001
        finalRgba = self.hsva_to_rgba(self.rainbow)
        self.cartel.color = finalRgba


class MoneyControlApp(App):
    def build(self):
        prog = MoneyControl()
        Clock.schedule_interval(prog.update, 1.0 / 60.0)
        return prog

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MoneyControlApp().run()
```

kv file:

```
#:kivy 1.0.9

<MoneyControl@Widget>: #This works. Comment this line...
#MoneyControl:#RootWidget instance (as appears in documentation) # ...uncomment this one. It stops working.
    cartel: crt

    Label:
        id: crt
        font_size: 20
        center_x: root.width * 0.5
        top: root.height * 0.5
        text: "hola"
        color: 1, .3, .8, 1
```

The expected results would be after comment the first line of .kv file and uncomment the second one the example keeps working.

The actual results is, if you change the line, kivy arises an error about a property that is clearly working in the first case (so, no error).

I would like to know why is happening this, and of course, how to fix it (Only the fix without the reason of why happens this, would lead me/us to fall again in the same error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the two version of your `kv` file is that `<MoneyControl@Widget>:` is a rule for how to create a `MoneyControl` widget. While `MoneyControl:` actually creates a `MoneyControl` widget (that is ignored by your code). You need to change `MoneyControl:` to `<MoneyControl>:` so that you are comparing rules. Then they both work.

The docs a bit difficult to understand, but here are some key points:

In the `kv` file, `<>` indicates a rule. So `<MoneyControl>:` is a rule, and in the python code any `MoneyControl()` will follow that rule (including in the `build()` method).

A `MoneyControl:` in the `kv` file is instruction to build one instance of the `MoneyControl` widget. It is not a `rule`. It is only a root widget if it is not a child of any other rule or widget.

In the python code (including inside the `build()` method), `MoneyControl()` will create an instance of `MoneyControl`. If the `kv` included a `rule` for `MoneyControl`, then that rule will be followed in creating the instance. If there is no `rule`, then a new instance of `MoneyControl` is created without regard to the `kv` file.

In your `App`, if you have a `build()` method, then whatever that method returns is your apps `root` widget. You can call `MoneyControl()` in that method, and if there is a `rule` for it in the loaded `kv`, then that `rule` be followed. Or you can return the `root` widget  from the `kv` file, if you captured the returned `root` widget from loading the `kv` file (or string). For example, `theRoot = Builder.load_file('somefile.kv')` and `return theRoot`.

If your app does not have a `build()` method (or the `build()` method returns `None`), then a root widget from the appropriately named `kv` file will becode your apps `root` widget.

Comment: But, MoneyControl: wouldn't be the root widget (an instance acting as root). How can be it ignored by the code?.
Reading here: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html in "Rule context" part.
Then, is not correct to leave our "root widget" defined in .kv file without <> symbols?.

The right point is, the answer about why it doesn't works is because it is ignored... then, should we use factory or builder classes to get it working back, in the case without <> symbols as says in docs?. Or I completely missunderstanded the docs?...

Comment: See additional info in my answer above.

Comment: I see, things works differently at my original idea as I read in docs.

I've needed read it several times to understand everything, since in docs is mentioned about "rules", but there is no definition about what's exactly a rule itself.

But now more clear, no doubt, thanks for sharing knowledge!